# net_rim_xml_org not found

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I am getting following error while launching application on Blackberry device.

> Error : net_rim_xml_org not found

Comment: Which BlackBerry device are you using?

Comment: Blackberry Pearl 8100
os version 4.2.1.108

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by upgrading my device's O.S. to 4.5.0
That was the only solution left with me...
Now the application is working fine on the device...
Many thanks to all who helped me to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this if you compile with a version of the JDE that's more recent than the BlackBerry OS that you're running on - i.e. if you compile with JDE 4.5 and try to run on an OS 4.2 device.

Comment: I am using eclipse plugin,can I add more than one component packs to it?
So that I can run same code on multiple devices

Comment: Yes.  Go to the same spot you downloaded the eclipse plugin, get the appropriate zip file for the version you want and then use the eclipse software updates feature (Help->Software Updates) you have to add a new site, choose archive and point to the zip file on your local HD.